# Trying to get offset from lipo produces non-fat file error

Tags: macos, offset

I am trying to use lipo (http://www.unix.com/man-page/OSX/1/lipo/) to get a output such as this:

```
architecture x86_64
        cputype CPU_TYPE_X86_64
        cpusubtype CPU_SUBTYPE_X86_64_ALL
        offset 4096
        size 283008
        align 2^12 (4096)
```

I need it to get the offset value of a specific file.

When trying something like `lipo -info <file>` i get the following error message:

Non-fat file: AppleIntelSNBGraphicsFB is architecture: x86_64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The offset for x86_64 binarys is always 0.

If anyone wants to further explain this (or how to use lipo for "non-fat" files in general), feel free to do so.